# location.search.match in java script

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi everyone I'm beginner CTF player and I have same lake with javascript and I face following problem

I couldn't understand what is the intention of following line

```
location.search.match(/e=(.*)/)[1]))
```

This is complete code

```
        if(location.search) {
        var div = document.currentScript.parentNode.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
        div.className = 'alert alert-danger';
        div.role = 'alert';
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(unescape(location.search.match(/e=(.*)/)[1])));
    }
```

can u help me to understand it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`location.search`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp) basically give you the query string part of the current URL and and [`match`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) has been used to extract `e` parameter value from the query string with a regular expression.

As an example, if the current URL is like

`https://www.example.com/?e=someone@example.com` then `location.search.match(/e=(.*)/)[1]` will give you 'someone@example.com'.

Rest of the code basically create a div element and set extracted text as a child of it and finally append that div as a child of parent node of the currently running script tag.

Comment: 1. The code is trying to create a 'div' element document.currentScript.parentNode.  2. Div class is being added as 'alert alert-danger' 3. the partial url is being appended inside dive in this case 'someone@example.com'

Comment: Since its partial code I can not help more than this but if you provide full script with HTML I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working example:

This URL have multiple query parameters, such as: config=xxx & zoom=17 & lat=xxx etc...

I want to extract each query parameters one by one.

```
http://localhost:10/mapserver1/viewer/?config=viewer_simple1&mapserver_url=https://maps2.dcgis.dc.gov/dcgis/rest/services/Zoning/MapServer&zoom=17&lat=38.917292&long=-77.036420
```

This is how you do (working code):

```
        var ___zoom = location.search.match(/zoom=([^&]*)/i)[1];
        var ___lat = location.search.match(/lat=([^&]*)/i)[1];
        var ___long = location.search.match(/long=([^&]*)/i)[1];
        var ___basemap = location.search.match(/basemap=([^&]*)/i)[1];


        var ___type = location.search.match(/type=([^&]*)/i)[1];
        var ___url = location.search.match(/url=([^&]*)/i)[1];
        var ___title = location.search.match(/title=([^&]*)/i)[1];
        var ___opacity = location.search.match(/opacity=([^&]*)/i)[1];


        //console.log(location.search.match(/zoom=([^&]*)/i)[0]);   //    'zoom=17'
        //console.log(location.search.match(/zoom=([^&]*)/i)[1]);   //     '17'
        console.log(___zoom); 
        console.log(___lat); 
        console.log(___long); 
        console.log(___basemap); 

        console.log(___type); 
        console.log(___url); 
        console.log(___title); 
        console.log(___opacity);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my fully working code:

first check if parameter exist, if does, then extract it.

```
        var ___zoom;
        var ___lat;
        var ___long;
        var ___basemap;

        var ___type;
        var ___url;
        var ___title;
        var ___opacity;


        /*
         *  if (value) { 
         *     
         *  }
         * 
         * will evaluate to true if value is not:

                null
                undefined
                NaN
                empty string ("")
                false
                0
         * 
         * 
         * 
         */


        if ( location.search.match(/zoom=([^&]*)/i) )
        {
             ___zoom = location.search.match(/zoom=([^&]*)/i)[1];
         }

        if ( location.search.match(/lat=([^&]*)/i) )
        {
           ___lat = location.search.match(/lat=([^&]*)/i)[1];
        }

        if (location.search.match(/long=([^&]*)/i))
        {
            ___long = location.search.match(/long=([^&]*)/i)[1];
        }

        if (location.search.match(/basemap=([^&]*)/i))
        {
            ___basemap = location.search.match(/basemap=([^&]*)/i)[1];
        }

        if (location.search.match(/type=([^&]*)/i))
        {
            ___type = location.search.match(/type=([^&]*)/i)[1];
        }

       if (location.search.match(/url=([^&]*)/i))
        {
            ___url = location.search.match(/url=([^&]*)/i)[1];
        }


        if (location.search.match(/title=([^&]*)/i))
        {
            ___title = location.search.match(/title=([^&]*)/i)[1];
        }

        if (location.search.match(/opacity=([^&]*)/i))
        {
            ___opacity = location.search.match(/opacity=([^&]*)/i)[1];
        }


        //console.log(location.search.match(/zoom=([^&]*)/i)[0]);   //    'zoom=17'
        //console.log(location.search.match(/zoom=([^&]*)/i)[1]);   //     '17'
        console.log(___zoom); 
        console.log(___lat); 
        console.log(___long); 
        console.log(___basemap); 

        console.log(___type); 
        console.log(___url); 
        console.log(___title); 
        console.log(___opacity);
```